# Aligning checkbox and button

Tags: html, css

I am trying to align under a login form with username and password, on the left a checkbox saying "Remember me?" and on the right a Login button , but I can't figure out how to align them properly.Currently they are out of their desired position and it looks bad
The code for the checkbox and the login button are at the end of the css - label.custom-checkbox and .loginbutton

```
    <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="form.css">
    <style>

body, html, div, p {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}
body {
    padding: 5px;
    font-family: Verdana;
}

#loginbox {
    width: 700px;
    height: 300px;
    background: #e6e6e6;
}

#heding {
    font-family: Verdana;
    font-weight: 600;
    font-size: 22px;
    color: #3B5998;
    padding: 5px;
}

#register {
position: relative;
left: 3%;
top: 4%;   
}
.necessery {
    color: grey;
    font-size: 12px;
    padding: 5px;
}
#reg-submit {
    width: 150px !important;
    background-color: #e6e6e6;
    border: 2px solid #3B5998 !important;
    border-radius: 0px !important;
    height: 30px !important;
    margin-left: 105px !important;
}

#register input {
    display: block;
    margin-top: 10px;
    border: 1px solid #b3b3b3;
    border-radius: 2px;
    width: 35%;
    height: 22px;
    padding: 2px;
    padding-left: 8px;
}
.reg-hud {
    font-weight: 600;
    color: grey;
    font-size: 18px;
}
a {
    text-decoration: none;
}
a .f-blue {
    color: #3B5998;
}

#login {
    background-color: #3B5998;
    padding: 10px;
    position: relative;
    float:right;
    right: 15%;
    bottom: 67%;

}

.log-hud {
    color: white;
    font-weight: bold;
}
.login-div input {
    display: block;
    margin-top: 10px;
    border: 1px solid #b3b3b3;
    border-radius: 2px;
    width: 245px;
    height: 22px;
    padding: 2px;
    padding-left: 8px;
}

.login-div {
    text-align: center;
}

#checkbox  {
    float: none;
    width: auto;
    display: inline-block;
}

#checkbox-label {
    font-size:12px;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    margin-top: 13px;
    color: #fff;
}



label.custom-checkbox input[type="checkbox"] {
        float:left;

    opacity:0;
}

label.custom-checkbox input[type="checkbox"] ~ .helping-el{
    background-color: #5072A7;
    border: 4px solid white;  
    border-radius: 2px;

    display: inline-block;
    padding: 10px;

    position: relative;
    top: 2px;


}

label.custom-checkbox input[type="checkbox"]:checked ~ .helping-el{
    border: 4px solid #F8F8FF;
    background-color: #5072A7;

}

label.custom-checkbox input[type="checkbox"]:checked ~ .helping-el:after {
    color: #FFFFFF;
    content: "\2714";
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: normal;
    left: 2px;
    position: absolute;
    top: -6px;
    transform: rotate(10deg);
}



.loginbutton{
            border: 3px solid white;
            font-weight: bold;
            background-color: #5072A7;
            width: 15%;
            height: 30px;
            position: absolute;
            right: 20px;

            color: white

}
```

```
        <div id="loginbox">
        <p id="heding">Enter the system</p>
        <p class="necessery"> It is necessery to log in Your account in order to sign in for a course.</p>
            <div id="register">
                <div class="reg-hud">
                    ARE YOU NEW? <a href="#"><span class="f-blue">REGISTER</span></a>
                </div>
                <form>
                    <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="User name">
                    <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Email">
                    <input type="passowrd" name="pass" placeholder="Password">
                    <input type="password" name="pass" placeholder="Confirm Password">
                    <input type="submit" id="reg-submit" name="submit" value="Register">
                </form>
            </div>
            <div id="login">
                <div class="log-hud">
                    ALREADY A STUDENT? LOGIN
                </div>
                <form>
                    <div class="login-div">
                        <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="User name">
                        <input type="password" name="password" placeholder ="Password">


           <label class="custom-checkbox">
        <input type="checkbox" />
        <span class="helping-el"></span>
        <span class="span3">Remember me?</span>
        </label>

                <input type="submit" name="register" value="Login" class="loginbutton">




                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>

        </div>

My desired result is something like this :https://imgur.com/a/ICeuVUM
```

Answer (score 0):

in the first

```
label.custom-checkbox input[type="checkbox"] {
    /* float: left; */
    /* opacity: 0; */
    display: none;
}

.custom-checkbox{
    float:left;
}
```

and add class to Login button say login-btn to add width like this:

```
.login-btn{
    width: 30%;
}
```

this is result :

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Ok I changed a few styles in your code . I suggest you should use [flex-box](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_flexbox.asp) whenever you want to align content and try using more divs to wrap your elements. Avoid using important excessively. You can follow my code structure below. Its responsive as well along with perfectly aligned. Hope it helps :)

```css
body, html, div, p {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}
body {
    padding: 5px;
    font-family: Verdana;
}
.container{
      background: #e6e6e6;
      padding: 20px;
}
.heading{
      margin-bottom: 20px;
}

#register {
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}

#loginbox {
    background: #e6e6e6;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
}

#heding {
    font-family: Verdana;
    font-weight: 600;
    font-size: 22px;
    color: #3B5998;
    margin: 5px 0px;
}


.necessery {
    color: grey;
    font-size: 12px;
}
#reg-submit {
    width: 150px;
    background-color: #e6e6e6;
    border: 2px solid #3B5998;
    border-radius: 0px;
    float: right;
    height: 30px !important;
    margin: 15px 0px;
}

#register input {
    margin-top: 10px;
    border: 1px solid #b3b3b3;
    border-radius: 2px;
    width: 100%;
    /* height: 22px; */
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 5px;
    padding-left: 8px;
}
.reg-hud {
    font-weight: 600;
    color: grey;
    font-size: 18px;
    width: 100%;
}
a {
    text-decoration: none;
}
a .f-blue {
    color: #3B5998;
}

#login {
   background-color: #3B5998;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    /* position: relative; */
    /* float: right; */
    /* right: 15%; */
    /* bottom: 67%; */
    max-width: 100%;
}
.footer-container{
  display:flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  margin: 20px 0px;
}
.log-hud {
    color: white;
    font-weight: bold;
}
.login-div  input[type="text"],.login-div  input[type="password"] {
    margin-top: 20px;
    border: 1px solid #b3b3b3;
    border-radius: 2px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 5px 0px;
    padding-left: 8px;
}

.login-div {
    text-align: center;
}

#checkbox  {
    float: none;
    width: auto;
    display: inline-block;
}

#checkbox-label {
    font-size:12px;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    margin-top: 13px;
    color: #fff;
}



label.custom-checkbox input[type="checkbox"] {
    margin: 0px;
    width: 0px;
    opacity: 0;
}

label.custom-checkbox input[type="checkbox"] ~ .helping-el{
    background-color: #5072A7;
    border: 4px solid white;  
    border-radius: 2px;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 10px;

}
.custom-checkbox{
    display: flex;
    align-items: baseline;
    justify-content: space-between;
}
.span3{
  margin: 0px 10px;
}
label.custom-checkbox input[type="checkbox"]:checked ~ .helping-el{
    border: 4px solid #F8F8FF;
    background-color: #5072A7;

}

label.custom-checkbox input[type="checkbox"]:checked ~ .helping-el:after {
    color: #FFFFFF;
    content: "\2714";
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: normal;
    left: 2px;
    position: absolute;
    top: -6px;
    transform: rotate(10deg);
}



.loginbutton{
    border: 3px solid white;
    font-weight: bold;
    background-color: #5072A7;
    width: 30%;
    height: 30px;
    color: white;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 768px){
  #loginbox {
    background: #e6e6e6;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
  }

}
```

```html
<div class="container">
 
   <div class="heading">
    <p id="heding">Enter the system</p>
    <p class="necessery"> It is necessery to log in Your account in order to sign in for a course.</p>  
    </div>

   <div id="loginbox">
    <div id="register">
      <div class="reg-hud">
        ARE YOU NEW? <a href="#"><span class="f-blue">REGISTER</span></a>
      </div>
      <form>
        <div>
        <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="User name">        
        </div>
        <div>
        <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Email"> 
        </div>
        <div>        
        <input type="passowrd" name="pass" placeholder="Password">
        </div>
        <div>        
        <input type="password" name="pass" placeholder="Confirm Password">
        </div>
        <button id="reg-submit" name="submit" value="Register">
          Register
        </button>
      </form>
    </div>
    <div id="login">
      <div class="log-hud">
        ALREADY A STUDENT? LOGIN
      </div>
      <form>
        <div class="login-div">
          <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="User name">
          <input type="password" name="password" placeholder ="Password">
          <div class="footer-container">
              <label class="custom-checkbox">
                  <input type="checkbox" />
                  <span class="helping-el"></span>
                  <span class="span3">Remember me?</span>
              </label>
              <button  name="submit"  class="loginbutton">
              Login
             </button>
          </div>

        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Thanks , but  is it possible to lower the gap between the two form and put the register button little on the right?